# Please help identify B-Movie with Earth turned into penitentiary

Tags: story-identification, b-movies

This one's a bit odd, sorry in advance. Saw it like a million years ago, when the Latin American Cinemax aired english-language B-flicks

It's a B-Movie done during the 90's (or early 2000's), regarding Earth being abandoned and being used as a prison planet, and the president of the federation (or whatever the heck it's called) crash-landing there with several members of his cabinet and his son, and a doctor that was sentenced there (and became a pretty badass warrior with a triple-barreled sawed-off in the time afterwards) helping them.

The Big Bad leader of the gang of evil prisoners makes a speech during the final act about Cortez and burning the ships as motivation, before activating a Ragnarok-Proofed super-nuke that cannot be disarmed and thus drives all of his remaining Mooks into a zealot-like frenzy (and of course, they get vaporised when the bomb explodes, while the good guys manage to escape).

Comment: Some definite similarities to [Escape from New York](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_from_New_York), but that doesn't have all the ingredients.

Comment: Some elements sound like the 1995 Judge Dredd, but not enough for it to me a match.

Comment: There was also a sequel to "Escape from New York" called "Escape form LA" released in 1996

Comment: It's not one of those-it's the whole planet, and was pretty much "B", while the "Escape" movies were "A".

Comment: Perhaps just [Prison Planet](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0140471/)? Plot seems to differ a little, but a lot of the elements are there.

Comment: No, it isn't. However, I gotta thank you for the link. Looks pretty good… you know, for a B-Flick.

Comment: "Escape" movies were "A" . . . _really dude_?

Comment: "Escape" movies were "A", but this was definitely "B" to "Z"-grade. Saw it on Cinemax when Cinemax bothered to show movies that were more than just sex and gloom.

Comment: FORTRESS 2 is one possibility, though it's a satellite prison . . . NO ESCAPE is another, but that's on an island rather than a planet though everything else matches pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

It's [Survivor (1998)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0157079/), but the summary is incorrect in IMDB.

You can view the Russian trailer for this movie (marketed as "from the creators of the mega-blockbuster DNA (1997)" :-) ) [here](http://www.kinopoisk.ru/film/54424/).

A summary from one of the IMDB reviews:

> After mankind moved into space, the old planet Earth is forgotten, a polluted wasteland where only expelled prisoners still survive. One of them is Tarkin (Xavier Declie). When a capsule with the president lands on Earth, Kyla (Richard Moll) captures the politician because he knows a spaceship will come to the rescue, and that will be his chance to get off the prison planet. Tarkin, however, fights Kyla to free the president. While Kyla rules over an army of gladiators, Tarkin has to rely on the president's little grandson...

Comment: Could you add some more details about this film (e.g. by quoting from the links)? Link-only answers tend to be discouraged here, since the links could expire and render the answer useless.

Comment: In particular, if the IMDB plot summary is bad, could you find (or write) a better one?

Comment: Also, one can submit corrections to IMDB. Please consider doing so.